# Google advertising ID Returning Null on Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, google-advertising-id

I am using advertising id in my app and the code was working fine util I tested it on a device running Android Nougat 7.1.2. Can you point out what should I add to get it in Nougat too ?

```
private static void getAdvertisingID() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            AdvertisingIdClient.Info idInfo = null;
            try {
                idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(_context);
                if (idInfo.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled()){ // check if user has opted out of tracking
                    Log.i("NetworkStateChangeReceiver","Not Found");
                    return "did not found GAID... sorry";
                }
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String advertId = null;
            try{
                advertId = idInfo.getId();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return advertId;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String advertId) {
            Log.i("NetworkStateChangeReceiver","Found "+advertId);
            UtilHelper.setDeviceIDFA(advertId);
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the code works fine, only problem is that on Nougat it takes some to call `onPostExecute` method, while on other devices running lower android version this method is called quickly. I just added some delay to get the advertisement id after calling `getAdvertisingID` and everything worked out fine.
Happy coding